# Is it normal to see oscillations in tested hyperparameters during bayesian optimisation?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, hyperparameter-optimization, bayesian-optimization

I've been trying out bayesian hyperparameter optimisation (with TPE) on a simple CNN applied to the MNIST handwritten digit dataset. I noticed that over iterations of the optimisation loop, the tested parameters appear to oscillate slowly.

Here's the learning rate:
[image]

Here's the momentum:
[image]

I won't add a graph, but the batch size is also sampled from one of 32, 64, or 128. Also note that I did this with a fixed **10 epochs** in each trial.

I understand that we'd expect the trialled parameters to converge gradually towards the optimal, but why the longer term movement of the average?

For context here is the score (1 - accuracy) over iterations
[image]

And also for context, here's the architecture of the CNN.

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 13, 13, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 11, 11, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 9, 9, 64)          36928     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100)               102500    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1010      
=================================================================
```

Optimization done with mini-batch gradient descent on the cross entropy.